# AppCompat - how to restore SearchView

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview

I can open the SearchView, but whatever I tried, I can't restore the search content...

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_phone_contacts_list, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    if (DataManager.get().getLastContactFilter() != null)
    {
        MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);

       // Variant 1 - does not work:
       searchView.setQuery(DataManager.get().getLastContactFilter(), false);

       // Variant 2 - does not work either:
       searchView.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               searchView.setQuery(DataManager.get().getLastContactFilter(), false);
           }
       });
    }
```

Variant 3 was restoring the content in following function:

```
  @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    if (DataManager.get().getLastContactFilter() != null)
    {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setQuery(DataManager.get().getLastContactFilter(), false);
    }
}
```

but no variant did work...

Answer (score 0):

Use static MenuItemCompat's method to get the SearchView

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
searchView.setQuery("myQueryText", false);
```

and check the xml item menu, it needs like "app" prefix (not platform related)

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```